# Binding to Element height Plus a value

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10

I wanna bind my element height to another element height plus 20 pixel...

Is it possible to do such a thing?

```
<ScrollViewer Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=AnotherElement}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using a value converter

```
public class IncreaseByValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var passedInValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        var increaseByValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);

        return passedInValue + increaseByValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

defined as a static resource somewhere in your resources:

```
<local:IncreaseByValueConverter x:Key="IncreaseByValueConverter" />
```

used like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=AnotherElement, Converter={StaticResource IncreaseByValueConverter}", ConverterParameter="20">
```

You'll probably want to handle the converter parameter better by using some try/catch code in the IncreaseByValueConverter.Convert method. For example, make the parameter optional, so if it's not passed in, use a default value, or something like that...